# LTspice Model Stopped Working

Tags: ltspice, three-phase

Tried to model an equivalent circuit for a 3-phase TN-S system to model inrush behaveour. Was working for a while, and now nothing beyond the "Power Cable".

Probably an obvious reason, but unable to find it.. appreciate any help.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: .asc Download: https://filebin.net/9yps86zznic5keos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably had a `.model` card for your diode but deleted it? At any rate, you're using the default diode, without any settings, which means it's an ideal diode that has zero voltage drop and sharp knees in its transfer characteristics. If you'll add this to your schematic, it should work:

```
.model d d ron=10m roff=10meg vfwd=0.7 vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=50m
```

If, by any chance, you still have glitches, try adding some `1m...10m` series resistance to the capacitors (right-click on the capacitors).

Be careful how you reference your nodes, because you have named the ground (zero, `0`) net as both `N` and `PE` -- you won't be able to plot anything referenced to these names (i.e. `V(L3,N)` will not work).

Comment: Thanks, looks like using non-ideal diodes resolved the glitch. I was actually concerned about that when I drew the first rectifier bridge, but it worked for a while, so I forgot about it and kept using the standard ideal D model.